# Error: Unable to display this Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I am receiving the following error message when trying to display my web part.

```
Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in
a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft 
SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

Correlation ID:e1c61ac1-788a-46c6-9311-495a5fa0603f
```

I had gone to Central Administration, to the Secure Store Services and created the "Target Application ID" and have already set permissions and credentials. Also, I have set the permissions in the "Business Data Connectivity Application". This removed the - BDC and NT\Authority errors that I had, now I have the error noted above and don't remember how to remove it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs? Check 14\LOGS and see if any errors are logged at the same time. Also, if you don't have it turned on already, enable the developer dashboard and view the trace log for the page.  See here to enable to the dashboard: http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/10/28/using-the-developer-dashboard-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: @Kyle- Im more than sure everything is sat up since this is not the first external content type that I have worked with and I just forgot how to resolve this issue and don't remember where I found the 'helps'. I am new to sharepoint and remember the last time I had this same error message, I didnt have to go into PowerShell and if I dont have to, I'd rather not.

Comment: I still recommend enabling the developer dashboard -- it will help you identify the exact error that is occuring, and without that diagnosing this problem will be a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Fixed it! What I learned is that parameters were not set. This has happened to me twice. When parameters/filters are not set, the return of data is too large to be passed and an error as the one noted is given. I tried going back to add filters/parameters, but instead recreated the ECT, the only difference was this time filters were added. :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is correct - if the webpart attempts to retrieve too much data, it displays this error. But it is also displayed if you are attempting to create an External List, and have not specified the desired list view. This may sound simple, but it confused me for a while. If you have created the list (and have set the filter parameters/throttling values correctly) and get this error, go to "Edit web part" and in the View box, you will probably see something like , but if you change it to your default "[Content type name] Read List", the data should display correctly. 
The error also occurs, if the XSLT Stylesheet is invalid. If you have edited the code manually, and it is flawed, it displays this error message.

Answer (score 0):

[Another reason](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/38e44006-93f4-414f-8016-0a9fbb085730/unable-to-display-this-web-part-to-troubleshoot-the-problem-open-this-web-page-in-a-microsoft) is that XSL Transformation takes longer than 1 sec (by default).

Answer (score 0):

**Note**:I'm running into this issue using a 3rd party forms designer. Within this designer, it provides some options for CSS styling to their controls. For some reason, adding styles to the controls was making this error arise.

So, if you're using 3rd party, or even if not, try to remove all applied CSS to make sure it's not something as simple as that.

---

Sorry for re-posting in such an old thread, want to provide more solutions if anyone else can't get it solved via the above posts.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the resources the webpart is using has the right permissions.
For Eg. The webpart may be accessing data from site assets/style library etc.
So check the permissions of user on the corresponding library from webpart.
If the user doesnt have the necessary permission then you wont be able to see the webpart n SP will give you error "Unable to display this Web Part"

It Worked for me.
Check!